# iPhone - Draw white text on black view using CGContext

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, text, colors, core-graphics

I can't achieve drawing some white text on a black view using CGContext in a drawRect method.

I do :

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 20, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

CGPoint center = self.center;
```

And then...
Impossible to find the correct method.
I've tried this :

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Geneva" size:12.0];
[@"Some text" drawAtPoint:center withFont:font];
```

But it does not work.

I don't find any CGContext method for that. Where is it hidden ?

How may I draw that text in white ?

Comment: Your code looks mostly correct.  You don't need `CGContextSelectFont` or `CGContextSetTextDrawingMode`.  Also Double check that center is actually a reasonable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with :

```
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, center.x, center.y, "Some text", strlen("Some text"));
```

But still need some transformations to be displayed not mirrored :-)

Comment: Be careful.  Last I checked, this only works for ASCII, not Unicode.

Comment: `'CGContextShowTextAtPoint' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of OS X 10.9 and earlier are unavailable in Swift`

Answer (score 4):

Ok after a couple of hours and reading the Quartz 2D programming guide I discovered that you also have to set the FILL color, not just the STROKE color.  So the follow code works.

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
```

I needed to show chart labels on a darkGray border.  Now the labels appear in white.

Comment: Actually, you only need to set the fill color, the stroke color is not used by text

Comment: Note that you can also write `UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor` in Objective-C 2.0 dot syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This will draw a string in white in a black rectangle

```
NSString *text = @"Some text";
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(100, 200);
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

CGSize stringSize = [text sizeWithFont:font];
CGRect stringRect = CGRectMake(center.x-stringSize.width/2, center.y-stringSize.height/2, stringSize.width, stringSize.height);

[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(context, stringRect);

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[text drawInRect:stringRect withFont:font];
```

Comment: OK, but that didn't work. The method I give in my found solution solved the preblem (but text is mirrored).

Answer (score 1):

On shorter example try using `[[UIColor whiteColor] set]` before the `drawAtPoint:` call.

Comment: are you sure your drawRect: is being called? Just tried here with a small sample and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with this code :

```
NSString *text = @"Some text";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

[ text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake( 0, 0 ) withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor } ];
```